# Sending parameters with Fine Uploader upload requests

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I need to send parameters to a REST service called from AngularJs. I need to send some data besides the file, how can I send it, and how can I specify the file parameter?

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Either via the [`request.params` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#request):

```
request: {
    params: {
        param1: "foo",
        param2: "bar"
    }
}
```

or via the [`setParams` method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#setParams):

`uploader.setParams({param1: "foo", param2: "bar"});`

You can adjust the name of the file parameter via the [`request.inputName` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#request).

All of this is documented.  Please see the documentation for additional information and supported workflows related to setting parameters.

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to know if I can do reference to the file object as a parameter, I need to send separately the model, and the file as bytes.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do.  The file is sent to your server as a parameter (in the request body), for all intents and purposes.